# Unity2D X Axis Velocity is Zero Towards the Left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity2D to make a top down shooter. When I shoot bullets out of the player to the right, everything works fine, but when I do it to the left, the y velocity remains correct and the x velocity remains 0. There is a `Rigidbody2D` attached to the bullet and I edit the velocity directly to make sure it doesn't change later. I tried `Debug.Log(transform.rotation)` to see if the rotation was correct, and it is. I tried `transform.eulerAngles`, and it made no difference in the result. I also tried avoiding using `transform.up` by setting the velocity directly with a `Vector2`, and that didn't work either. Here is the code:

```
void Update()
{
  if(playerHealth.playerStamina > 0 && timeUntilFire <= 0 && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
  {
    GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb.velocity = transform.up * speed;
  }
}
```

The stuff in the if statement is just for verifying that the player can and wants to shoot a bullet, and this script is attached to a `GameObject` that rotates around the player (the gun) towards the mouse. There is no other code in the project that edits the velocity or angle of the bullets being fired.

Comment: It seems like the issue might be related to the orientation of your gun and how you are calculating the bullet's velocity based on that orientation. If the gun is rotating correctly but the bullets are not moving in the expected direction, there might be a discrepancy in how the velocity is being applied.

Comment: So, with the code I showed you above, where is that discrepancy? Like I said, I logged the rotation of the bullet at instantiation and it was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void Update()
{
    if (playerHealth.playerStamina > 0 && timeUntilFire <= 0 && Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

        // Get the forward direction in world space
        Vector2 shootingDirection = transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up);

        rb.velocity = shootingDirection * speed;
    }
}
```

`Transform.TransformDirection(Vector2.up)` will get the local up direction of the gun and then transforms it to world space. This should ensure that the bullet moves in the direction the gun is facing, regardless of its local rotation.

Comment: It didn't do anything different than from the code I already had.

Answer (score 0):

I later figured out that it was because the player's `Rigidbody2D` had too much mass, and it was interacting with the `Rigidbody2D` of the bullet prefab.